# symmetric matrix - definiteness of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=[a_{i,j}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is positive definit. Then:
a. $a_{i,j} > 0$ for $i,j=1,...,n$
b. $a_{i,i} > 0$ for $i=1,...,n$
c. matrix $A$ is nonsingular.

c. is true, it is easy thanks to Sylvester criterion.  In particular, $\det A_n = \det A > 0$

a. is not true, counterexample: 
$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
5 & -2 \\
-2 & 5 \\
 \end{array} \right] $ is symettric and determinants = $5, 21$.  So matrix is symmetric and positively definit, but $-2 < 0$.

b.  it is false, conterexample:
$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
-5 & -2 \\
-2 & -5 \\
 \end{array} \right]
$

Am I ok?

Comment: You counterexample for b) is not valid, since your matrix is not positive definit. ($det A_1 = -5 < 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like  pos def  means strictly pos def.

For (a) ok. You have used Sylvester perfectly (alternatively you might notice that it is symmetric and calulate the evals [which are positive]).

For (b) it is not ok. Recall that (strictly) pos def means $x^T A x> 0$ for any non-zero vector $x$ and you may try with $x=e_i$ (canonical basis).

For (c) it is fine. A bit more details: pos def is quivalent to all the principal minors being positive. So in particular pos def implies that the full determinant is (strictly) positive so $A$ is non-singular. But your argument is fine.

Comment: what about c. ?

Comment: c is fine. By Sylvester pos def is equivalent to all principal minors having (strictly) pos dets. So in particular for the n'th as you state.

Comment: When it comes to (a) I don't understand you. I shown symmetric matrix. Each principal determinants is strictly positive. Hence, matrix is positivly definit. As for (c) - could you edit your post and clear this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right about (a). Your response is perfect!
I'll edit my post fro the rest.